# Using spring:bind and spring:eval together

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am not able to understand the use of spring:eval inside spring:bind in the following code.

```
     <spring:bind path="someProperty">    
         <spring:eval expression="${status.path}"/>
      </spring:bind>
```

Can somebody shed light on why one would want to use spring:eval inside spring:bind ?